# How to add the multiple XML tag value using Shell script

Tags: shell

sed -Ei "s/( key="ak.scahma..name")></\1>$ak_pwd</" ,"s/( key="bk.schma.password1")></\1>$bk_pwd</" test.xml

Error: sed: can't read ,: No such file or directory

I need to add the xml tag value "bk.password" and "ak.password" in XML file by running a shell script. How can I achieve this using sed with single line? Give me an example please.

Comment: you seem to have dbl-quotes within dbl-quotes. Recommand you experiment with `sed -Ei 's@..."...."..@....@' file`. Use `@` and then you don't have to escape any `/' chars that are part of your srchTarget or ReplaceStr. Good luck.

Comment: While experimenting, do not use `-i`